# Removing special characters in a string in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a data frame where I want to remove all the **round brackets** that are found in a specific column. In this case in column Z. The code that I have written only removes some of the round brackets. It removes the first brackets that it encounters and leaves out the rest. Could I get some assistance as to how I could go about to remove all the round brackets. Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)
FRUIT <- data.frame("X" = c(1,2,3), 
                 "Y" = c("A1", "A2", "A3"),
                 "Z" = c('[LEMON(ORANGE)xxx[LEMON(GRAPE)]', "[PEAR(APPLE)]xxxORANGE(APPLE)", "PEACHxxx[APR(ICOT)]"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The output datafarme is

```
X Y   Z
1 A1   [LEMON(ORANGE)xxx[LEMON(GRAPE)]
2 A2   [PEAR(APPLE)]xxxORANGE(APPLE)
3 A3   PEACHxxx[APR(ICOT)]
```

The code that I have tried to remove the brackets is below:

```
fruit2<-FRUIT%>%
  mutate(Z=str_remove(Z,"\\("))%>%
  mutate(Z=str_remove(Z,"\\)"))
```

The problem with this code is that it does not remove all the brackets. It only removes the ones that it encounters first and leaves out the rest. The out put is below:

```
 X Y   Z
 1 A1   [LEMONORANGExxx[LEMON(GRAPE)]
2 A2   [PEARAPPLE]xxxORANGE(APPLE)
3 A3   PEACHxxx[APRICOT]
```

My desired output is :

```
 X Y   Z
 1 A1   [LEMONORANGExxx[LEMONGRAPE]
2 A2   [PEARAPPLE]xxxORANGEAPPLE
3 A3   PEACHxxx[APRICOT]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to replace `str_remove` with `str_remove_all` and you'll get the desired output:

```
FRUIT %>%
  mutate(Z = str_remove_all(Z, "\\(")) %>%
  mutate(Z = str_remove_all(Z, "\\)"))

#>   X  Y                           Z
#> 1 1 A1 [LEMONORANGExxx[LEMONGRAPE]
#> 2 2 A2   [PEARAPPLE]xxxORANGEAPPLE
#> 3 3 A3           PEACHxxx[APRICOT]
```

Comment: Also, as a suggestion, instead of using `mutate()` twice to do two removals, you can do it once as `FRUIT %>% mutate(Z = str_remove_all(Z, "\\(|\\)"))`. The `|` operator in the regular expression means "or", as in applying the function to `\\(` OR `\\)`.